# Dynamically change the xml file location that flash loads using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash, actionscript-3

Can someone tell me how i can change the .xml file that a flash movie loads using c#.  ie: i would like an ActionScript variable that defines the location of the flash movie. I would like to be able to change this variable using c# if possible.

i dont really know how it would look, but something like:

```
<object xmlpath='" + myCSharpVar + "'" ...></object>
```

I just starting this, but my ultimate goal is to create a .swf movie that can load an xml file that specifies images, etc.  However i want to use the same .swf file in multiple places and only have to change a ref to what xml file it uses - and my Flash/ActionScript skills are very rusty.

To clear it up a bit, in AS you can do something like:

```
loader.load( new URLRequest("IWantThisNameDynamic.xml") );
```

how can i define that xml file in my c# code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure you cannot "create" your own attributes for the object tag. At least not without consulting with the w3c ;-)

Passing values to flash is done via the "flashvar"-param:

```
  <object ...>
    <param name="flashvars" value="&xmlpath=<path to xml>"/>
  </object>
```

In the flash-movie you can now access the path to your xml via the "xmlpath"-variable.

Comment: LOL - that was just for demo purposes - im sure it would have been much clearer if i did it in the param, but i honestly didnt know where it went.  Thanks for the reply, i still may ask w3c and tell them its for a special project - ha ha --- thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** sorry, question was about ASP.NET

If you were using an AxShockwaveFlash object in C#, you would set the variables this way:

```
AxShockwaveFlash movie; // already exists
string xmlPath = "some path";
movie.FlashVars = "xmlPath=" + xmlPath; // url-encoded variables
```

Then in AS2:

```
var xmlPath:String = _level0.xmlPath;
```

Or in AS3:

```
var xmlPath:String = loaderInfo.parameters.xmlPath;
```